# Facebook Graph API since/until Not Working for Facebook Conversations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For other nodes, such as Posts, I can easily retrieve the posts newer than the specified date via `since`

**me/posts?fields=id,link,created_time&since=2017-05-23**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "344993862351965_654017808116234",
      "link": "http://www.news.com.au/world/europe/manchester-terrorist-wanted-maximum-carnage-british-pm-says/news-story/b47c5a33ac2c237b13ca31df4af84766",
      "created_time": "2017-05-24T07:19:53+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "344993862351965_654008634783818",
      "created_time": "2017-05-24T06:50:59+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "344993862351965_654007804783901",
      "created_time": "2017-05-24T06:47:31+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "344993862351965_653995944785087",
      "created_time": "2017-05-24T05:58:28+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "344993862351965_653991941452154",
      "created_time": "2017-05-24T05:39:50+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "344993862351965_653572411494107",
      "created_time": "2017-05-23T03:36:03+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "344993862351965_653537714830910",
      "created_time": "2017-05-23T01:06:32+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "344993862351965_653536891497659",
      "created_time": "2017-05-23T01:02:51+0000"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5TXpORFE1T1RNNE5qSXpOVEU1TmpVNk9EWXdOelU1TlRRMU1EUTRPVEEyTmpVNE1BOE1ZAWEJwWDNOMGIzSjVYMmxrRHg4ek5EUTVPVE00TmpJek5URTVOalZAmTmpVME1ERTNPREE0TVRFMk1qTTBEd1IwYVcxbEJsa2xOQmtC",
      "after": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5UXpORFE1T1RNNE5qSXpOVEU1TmpVNkxUUTFNekE0TXpBNE1EUTVNemN5TVRrNU1EY1BER0ZA3YVY5emRHOXllVjlwWkE4ZAk16UTBPVGt6T0RZAeU16VXhPVFkxWHpZAMU16VXpOamc1TVRRNU56WTFPUThFZAEdsdFpRWlpJNG83QVE9PQZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

However, for Conversations, `since` doesn't work as expected, as you can see below (both of the results were created/updated older than 2017-05-23)

**me/conversations?fields=id,link,messages&since=2017-05-23&limit=2**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "t_mid.$cAAE5xQYTv8liRXo9xFcFDT0E7prs",
      "link": "/PowerToYou2/manager/messages/?threadid=10154252071796525&folder=inbox",
      "messages": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQYTv8liX8WWd1cLoBOBl1nb",
            "created_time": "2017-05-22T04:52:59+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQYTv8liUJT1Z1cH0-tTphzp",
            "created_time": "2017-05-19T06:05:34+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQYTv8liUJT0tlcH0-sDHM0e",
            "created_time": "2017-05-19T06:05:34+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQYTv8liRhbpE1cFNGgmoHRE",
            "created_time": "2017-05-17T05:11:41+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQYTv8liRe0p4lcFKfZ0lxol",
            "created_time": "2017-05-17T04:26:05+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQYTv8liRXo_TlcFDT2lzLiA",
            "created_time": "2017-05-17T02:20:34+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQYTv8liRXo9xFcFDT0E7prs",
            "created_time": "2017-05-17T02:20:34+0000"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "QVFIUllZAb2dxNS1pcHBDR0NEbW5DSG1YeF9fNTFJejBaZAnlTMTFZAR0JodTV4bnR3cVdkb3BOS1hLd3ZAIbjhrQjFoMV9QRXhDMnJNM3o5YkR6VnlVQ3AyTUpSYWVNNjNYLUlMUzVlYVJWalExZAGxRR1JSd3JjUjREY3NSNHpJdTVzQndF",
            "after": "QVFIUnFpQVlQam45a3owT3c1OHN3M2dlVmNBdWVSazRqUEJPUHo0eFNDSjFYaU5zNENyNm8zUW5mSWpydFpFeFJwTnI5cDA2cUI1ZAFcxZAHhtby1OVWhDcUlLV3UtUWV2OTl1NjZAIbW9kN2xjVDJsc25xUTBYVm9MVDN6OHpOR2ltREQ3"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "t_mid.1431568583280:8fb19e247dd7f96b70",
      "link": "/PowerToYou2/manager/messages/?threadid=101813436821767&folder=inbox",
      "messages": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiUICvylcHztndTcyi",
            "created_time": "2017-05-19T05:43:25+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiRVlSXFcFBQKOJ-GQ",
            "created_time": "2017-05-17T01:44:36+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiRVlSDVcFBQJ4x664",
            "created_time": "2017-05-17T01:44:36+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWqCH1b8CU5C0PsM",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:17:03+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWoYq1b8CTPLm2B0",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:16:36+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWmh21b8CRZEbhoS",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:16:05+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWlScFb8CQJmwmL6",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:15:45+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWlQJlb8CQHlvG5-",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:15:44+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWlLiFb8CQC-LmYc",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:15:43+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWk4-Vb8CPvwCeJz",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:15:39+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWkVslb8CPM4rnZ4",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:15:29+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWi_DVb8CN2AStE3",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:15:07+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWiBzlb8CM5t0o13",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:14:52+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIWiA_lb8CM39AMEr",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T02:14:51+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIVcrA1b8BHhpl4kK",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T01:55:55+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiIVcEg1b8BG1qtyg4",
            "created_time": "2017-05-10T01:55:45+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiHDJz6Vb6u0rIpZhn",
            "created_time": "2017-05-09T01:57:43+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFiHB3bu1b6tiTeNg_T",
            "created_time": "2017-05-09T01:35:13+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFh4zlcKFbsfQTOvDSo",
            "created_time": "2017-04-28T00:26:54+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFh4zYp41bsfDhjcpQl",
            "created_time": "2017-04-28T00:23:25+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFh4ytZkVbseYRPf5P-",
            "created_time": "2017-04-28T00:11:36+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFh4ym_SlbseR2uaJbr",
            "created_time": "2017-04-28T00:09:51+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFh3iXOyFbrOCGdgtC1",
            "created_time": "2017-04-27T00:47:27+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFh3iAp_FbrNrh4EVyC",
            "created_time": "2017-04-27T00:41:17+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAE5xQeNcgFh3iApklbrNrgvnUJA",
            "created_time": "2017-04-27T00:41:17+0000"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "QVFIUmFNLW5DMEFSUXpGVEM1RVNXd2RiQXlaejA5VGdVWHdMWUVKLVRZAZAlB2MC11M3NGUGhlanF4TEJlT1NJeUR6SDB0NjN4U2tfMXpvRnlXX01ONGRYMXRnMmFVR1dkd2xwdTZAneFlwNGp2QjRJR1VqZAjE0QlIxNC1DejdKQkRIY3E5",
            "after": "QVFIUkgyV2RZAOXlKM3FwSG9iZAVNNX01tY282LWFiclZAieHNac1ZA0TmpuREo4UzJ0enNOZA05QRW4xaDQ3UVc0VGttY1RnWXFKTUYyXzRXRklGZA2lsWVdYWWs0Q3ZABYWp2UzJIOUFFczJOTWlrY1BySi1CM0VQRnBZAR2VkbTdITVdMVkVy"
          },
          "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/t_mid.1431568583280:8fb19e247dd7f96b70/messages?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAIRioxeAWt3en2ZBQqKKy3X8BgPkxk86YZBoRMKFFRgRCEsMxV9g4WZAUMtddovO4aLyjytSFZBELWIfBChD4ZALKRs0kowEl3MLJ9TIbqOZB3Ggt6SGX5pCA1xSZB8fGgRUi2qxGtedFzlR0UZCG5p9wgZBTtrL07CqZA02PvT2SFsxTd12PQx3sZD&pretty=0&limit=25&after=QVFIUkgyV2RZAOXlKM3FwSG9iZAVNNX01tY282LWFiclZAieHNac1ZA0TmpuREo4UzJ0enNOZA05QRW4xaDQ3UVc0VGttY1RnWXFKTUYyXzRXRklGZA2lsWVdYWWs0Q3ZABYWp2UzJIOUFFczJOTWlrY1BySi1CM0VQRnBZAR2VkbTdITVdMVkVy"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUjJXamlwVXZAlS2tiMW1lVWIzQXpJWFlmeDNwdnBjenVxZAU11R3FMYTRmUkFuUHJya0tnbEczbV8yTzlGSndXa0RSdFVLUjU0d1RzTVRhN1k4TjM2TE0tNDBXNUZA0VGk3Qm9xX3gtSEFvZAUxvSEMwMXN5LTAxNkpsN3lmRmtPZAHR3",
      "after": "QVFIUnFUdmZAscEprU1AzNjJ1U3VkVTZAZAdFlCaVZAhNktkRkM2aHkzVkRYN0oyWXZAkaUhRMVcwUDFHLVlDQi15bmlvcFNLNFBReTRQN3AwbFlZAQi03U2ZASYXJuRmh3QlZAuTlB1V1FtS0hCRWRwRlcyX3FxYllETlhQQmltM0FuQVAtSWVt"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/344993862351965/conversations?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAIRioxeAWt3en2ZBQqKKy3X8BgPkxk86YZBoRMKFFRgRCEsMxV9g4WZAUMtddovO4aLyjytSFZBELWIfBChD4ZALKRs0kowEl3MLJ9TIbqOZB3Ggt6SGX5pCA1xSZB8fGgRUi2qxGtedFzlR0UZCG5p9wgZBTtrL07CqZA02PvT2SFsxTd12PQx3sZD&pretty=0&fields=id%2Clink%2Cmessages&limit=2&after=QVFIUnFUdmZAscEprU1AzNjJ1U3VkVTZAZAdFlCaVZAhNktkRkM2aHkzVkRYN0oyWXZAkaUhRMVcwUDFHLVlDQi15bmlvcFNLNFBReTRQN3AwbFlZAQi03U2ZASYXJuRmh3QlZAuTlB1V1FtS0hCRWRwRlcyX3FxYllETlhQQmltM0FuQVAtSWVt"
  }
}
```

According to the Facebook documentation, I believe all nodes should support time-based pagination, but only `conversations` and `messages` don't work as supposed.

I don't want to fetch the private messages and manually check the updated time to filter out the old messages because all of other nodes use `since` to filter the results and also, manually filtering the results is not a long-term solution.

Any alternatives for fetching Facebook messages by specified date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug regarding this issue and is also been reported.

Your can see the link here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/420363721670492/

Hope it get fixed soon.

Comment: thanks informing me that. it seems that i have to manually check the updated time of the thread and the created time of the message. extra loops are needed. sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook removed it. They told that in this bug report.

I think we should develop a new way to grab only new conversations/message (best pratices) in facebook without having to fetch all data every time.

Comment: totally agree. but messages do not support Time-based Pagination

Comment: I`m saving last message datetime for a page in a database, then when I fetch messages, if there`s an equal/old message time for that I have in database, I stop fetching. This way I grab only new ones.